In PCA, can certain variables be weighted?
I am working with a large dataset of disease symptoms which are all rated on a numeric scale (0-4 points per symptom). Some symptoms concern the left body half, some the right half, and some are axial (concern the centre of the body or the axis). Every row denotes a study participant. Here is an example created in R, but in reality there are many more symptoms:
> sampledata
 Speech        RigidityNeck  RigidityArmL RigidityArmR SpeedArmL    SpeedArmR 
 1             0             0            1            2            0                      
 0             0             0            0            0            0
 2             1             2            1            1            2
 1             1             1            1            2            0
 4             1             1            0            1            0 

Now, I would like to perform PCA and cluster analysis (I'm new to both approaches) with the goal of identifying patient subgroups. In the disease of interest, some people will have more symptoms on the right (e.g. more points in RigidityArmR), others on the left (RigidityArmL). RigidityNeck is an example for an axial symptom. The numbers can be added together to a total score (i.e. the sum of all columns) which is used to grade the severity of the disease. However, I don't want left vs right to be a feature of the PCs and I don't want to identify the subgroups "right-predominant" and "left-predominant". Rather, I expect to identify clusters such as "rigidity-predominant".
My question: Is there a way to remove the differentiation between left and right in this example? I don't think it would make sense to add the variables together to one variable (e.g. RigidityArmR + RigidityArmL = RigidityArmTotal), as this would reduce the magnitude of the side-specific symptoms relative to the axial symptoms; in other words, in this scenario, RigidityArmTotal would have the same impact on the analysis as RigidityNeck, although the parameter RigidityArm should have twice the impact (given that it's graded for both the left and the right). Or could I somehow assign twice the "weight" to RigidityArmTotal?
Please let me know if you require further clarifications!

Multiple Factor Analysis might be relevant here, e.g. you could assign RigidityArmR and RigidityArmL to the same group. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_factor_analysis
